# Scaled png files with transparency render with jagged edges in Internet Explorer 9 ( ie9 )

Tags: internet-explorer, graphics, png, transparency, internet-explorer-9

Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE8 all render the same png like this:

[image: correctly rendered png]

IE9 renders it like this:

[image: incorrectly rendered png]

This is the code:

```
<img src="/img/icon-grey-search.png" />
```

This is the css applied to this image:

```
img {
    height:1.5;
}
```

Why is this happening only in IE9? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Whats height:1.5; supposed to mean? That's not valid CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ms530822%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)